# Populate html form from url and auto submit

Tags: javascript

I'm using the below code to populate a form via URL but can this be modified to also auto submit the form?

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // grab the entire query string
    var query = document.location.search.replace('?', '');

    // extract each field/value pair
    query = query.split('&');

    // run through each pair
    for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
        // split up the field/value pair into an array
        var field = query[i].split("=");

        // target the field and assign its value
        $("input[name='" + field[0] + "'], select[name='" + field[0] + "']").val(field[1]);
    }
});
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Whatever your form id is invoke the `submit` method.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this line to the bottom of your script, but use your form's ID instead.

```
$("#MyFormId").submit();
```